# D7: Race condition(?) when deleting a node with lots of associated nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I've got a situation where I have a content type -- let's call it "book" -- which has a number of related nodes attached to it -- let's call them "chapters".  A user's home page shows snippets of each of the "books" that he's created on the site.

Now, comes the time when the user wants to delete one of these books.  As noted, each book has all those chapter nodes attached to it, so, when the book is deleted, the chapter nodes need to go away, too.  (It's actually worse than this -- in the real case, there is a LOT of stuff associated with a book, and it ALL has to be deleted.  But this will do for now.)

So I have something like:

```
 function book_node_delete($node) {
     try() { 
           // stuff
           node_delete_multiple(get_chapter_nids_of_book($node);
           // other stuff
     }
     catch (Exception $e) {
           ....
     }
 }
```

(The try/catch is there because, in the real situation, there's a LOT of DB stuff going on, and I'm trying to make sure that I always have a consistent database.)

Once the book is deleted, the user gets sent back to his home page, where he is meant to see the snippets of his remaining books.  But what I'm finding is that, when there are a lot of chapters and other stuff, Drupal sends the user back to the home page BEFORE all the deletion is done and the book node is completely deleted.  He therefore gets a home page with a listing of the just-deleted book.  This is wrong, of course, and leads to a 404 when the deletion actually finishes and the link in the snippet fails to resolve.

I've set up a bunch of watchdog statements tracking the deletion process, and this is definitely what's going on.  Is there any way around it? Thanks!

Comment: How do you know you the page is viewed before all deletion is completed? Is your deletion code in your hook is running asynchronously?

Comment: I put watchdogs at the start of book_node_delete() and the end of book_node_delete(), at the start of chapter_node_delete() (not mentioned above, but you get the idea) and at the beginning of the code that creates the user's home page.  The user home page code watchdog shows up about halfway through the reports from chapter_node_delete().  This of course depends on how fast the server is.